# Mathematica - creating a Bode Plot from a table or list of data

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, physics

I'm trying to create a bode plot with a line in *Mathematica*, i.e. log scale on x and dB on y. I have the following data table. Format is `{Frequency, Gain}`

```
{{10, 86.25}, {100, 82.8}, {1000, 82.4}, {10000, 81.6}, {100000, 40.83}, {1000000, 6.92}, {10000000, 0.95}}
```

I've been trying to get Bode Plot or Log Log Plot to work but they both only seem to take functions as arguments?

If that's the case how would I create a line plot with a log vs db scale? Really lost

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `ListLogLogPlot`

```
ListLogLogPlot[{{10, 86.25}, {100, 82.8}, {1000, 82.4}, {10000, 81.6},
   {100000, 40.83}, {1000000, 6.92}, {10000000, 0.95}}]
```

[image]

You said you are looking for a dB scale and Mathematica will default to a natural log scale. But you can look in the help system for `Ticks` and see if you can adjust the labels along the axes to match what you are looking for.